# Remove repeated n-grams from text with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-cleaning

I am starting to use `nltk` with `python` to analyse chat corpora. To start, I would like to identify the most use words, then I would like to use LDA to identify the topics of the conversations.
I clean the texts as:

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
stop.update(['.', ',', '"', "'", '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[',']', '{', '}', '@', '#', 'http', 'https', '/', '://', '_'])
p_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
texts = ['bla bla xxxxxx', 'hahahah', 'haha xx', ... 'hello xx']
```

Many of the words that I analyse consists of `xxxxx`, `xxx` and `x` or `hahaha` or `hahahaha`. After the preprocessing I obtain separated values for `xxxx` and `xx` etc. How can I consider `xxxx` and `xx` (or `hahaha` and `ha`  as the same words? Is there any function that allow me to do that?